# Is there a way to avoid emulator relaunch for application testing?

Tags: android

I've recently started working with Android. Currently to test an appl. I launch an emulator every time. Can I make changes to the program and test it again without having to restart the emulator? I'm using ADT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to close and relaunch the emulator.. let it be on and just push the run button again.. it will install the modified apk on the emulator and run just as if it's device connected.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you relaunch the emulator?

Just run it once, and recompile your application. 
If you use [android studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) or [eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for your development, you will save a lot of time that way :).

Think about it. You don't have to reboot your phone each time you update an app :).

I suggest you read a bit more the excellent [documentation](http://developer.android.com/) for android developers from google if you're just starting out :).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is press the run button within your IDE such as Eclipse. If the emulator isn't running it will launch the emulator but then each time you next press the run button within Eclipse, your app will be installed and updated on the emulator, once updated, the new version of the app will automatically launch on the emulator.

You don't need to keep closing an re-launching the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the Run button in eclipse and your emulator will launch automatically(if it is set properly).If multiple emulators are there,then it may ask you to select which one for the app to be run on.Once an emulator is started for further compilations you just need to click the same Run button and it will do the compilation + update on your emulator automatically.

Also you can right click on the project then ->Run as->Android Application,in order to update/start the desired emulator.